# How to Redraw or Interpret This

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, diagram

I am really stumped at this:

[image: Diagram]

I've been mulling this over my head for literal hours. I am pretty sure there should be 4 currents, because there are at least nodes with 3 parallel resistors. I just have a really hard time reading why the currents are placed the way they are in a very awkward manner. I really think there should be an I4 at the third loop, but it may not be relevant to the questions... I'm not sure. Just to keep anyone from answering my HW questions, I blocked them out, for decency's sake.

I just really need help understanding why the currents are placed the way they are. Is it true there are only 3 currents? This setup makes it very hard for me to use KCL or KVL. Should I use KCL/KVL, or is there another way? I have figured out I1 using equivalent resistance, but now I'm stuck. One of the questions asks me to figure out I1, I2 and I3 using a source voltage, but how when I4 is missing?? I just don't know how to figure it out.

Please help.

Comment: Do not take the direction of a current arrow in a diagram as 'the truth'. Use it as-is,  but in the end you may get a negative result which means the actual current was the 'other way around'. By the way: also look what part of a diagram you can optimise by combining resistors.

Comment: Yes you could argue for '4 currents'. Your 'I3' is the sum of the currents through the R6 and (R5+R7) legs.

Comment: Also, Rs 5, 6 & 7 are just one resistor is you squint hard enough.

Comment: The circuit, for the purpose of analysis, can be reduced to 3 resistors.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that there would be a current in the other branch; they didn't include it but there's no reason you can't. It seems like that is what is really hanging you up mentally, so draw it in and proceed with your analysis.

Comment: @brhans - You are absolutely sure about that then? I will take your word for it!

Comment: Every branch in this circuit has a current. So you can label 5 to 6 currents here. The question is, whether you need them to solve your task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redraw the diagram to something that makes sense to you and it will help you see it. This would help me and I just redraw what you gave in a different manner.
[image]

Comment: The original circuit does not have a short across R8.

Comment: good catch... updated to avoid confusion

Answer (score 2):

- To avoid confusions, you can mark all the nodes in the circuit first. We know currents from different branches either enter or leave from a node. Also keep in mind the KCL. The total current entering a node = the total current leaving a node. Let us mark these in the circuit.
  [image]
- You can arbitarily assume and mark the direction of all branch currents at each node. Because in the end when we calculations the values of currents , we will end up with its original directions (-ve sign means, the direction is actually opposite to what we assumed).
- Now before you proceed, you can formulate some current relations in the 
  circuit using KCL.
  As you can see:

  At node A : \$ I_1 = I_2 + I_4 \$

  At node B : \$ I_4 = I_5 + I_6 \$

  At node C : \$ I_3 = I_5 + I_6 \$

  At node D : \$ I_7 = I_2 + I_3 \$

  From these we can deduce that \$ I_4 = I_3 , I_7 = I_1 = I_2 + I_3 \$. Using 
  KVL we can find all branch currents with these relations.
- If you want to use 'loop current' method to solve this circuit. You gotta assume 3 loop currents, for three closed loops you see there. Again solving for R5,R6,R7,R8 into a single equivalent resistance \$Z = ((R5 + R7)||R6) + R8 \$ , will reduce the circuit to a simpler one with only two loop currents to solve.

[image]